# Migrating the [struts] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

In Stack Overflow, I've seen that the [struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts) tag is "referenced" as [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1). I think that it's confusing as Struts has 2 major releases, each with its own architecture. It would be preferred if we could only have 2 specific struts tag: [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1) and [struts-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-2).

Is it possible to have the struts tag migrated to a relevant tag that relevant tag be used consistently? This might help also when received the appropriate bronze, silver and gold badge.

In essence, the following tags exists with regards to Struts x.y (`x` being major version, `y` being minor version)

- [struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts)
- [struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts1)
- [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1)
- [struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts2)
- [struts-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-2)