# Add synonyms for [struts1] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have several tags which refer to the same thing - [Struts 1 web framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts_1):

- [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1), 1080 questions
- [struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts1), 189 questions
- [struts-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1.x), 80 questions

Since we already have [struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts2) and it's synonym [struts-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-2), I suggest to add these synonyms for Struts version 1:
 [struts-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1.x) -> [struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts1), [struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1) -> [struts1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts1).

There are 2 slightly different meta questions regarding these tags, so it is not a dupe:

- [Migrating the struts tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295021/migrating-the-struts-tags)
   - OP suggests to leave only 2 tags ([struts-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-1), [struts-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts-2)), and burninate the rest.
- [Retag [struts1][struts-1][struts-1.x], etc. to [struts]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338485/retag-struts1struts-1struts-1-x-etc-to-struts)
   - OP suggests to leave only 1 tag ([struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/struts)), and burninate the rest.

But I don't agree with these requests, so I think it makes sense to post this one.

Comment: There already was a [struts-1]->[struts1] synonym. I added the other one.